# How to move points to another polygon based on attribute?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, geoprocessing, select-by-attribute, vector-grid

I have a point layer and a grid cell/fishnet layer. Each point falls within a grid cell. Now I want to move some of the points to another (the nearest) grid cell based on an attribute that exists in the attribute tables of both layers.

The attribute contains information on the neighbourhood. Some points fall within a grid cell where the value of this attribute is not equal for both layers. So, I want to move these points to the nearest grid cell that has the same value regarding this attribute.

Does anyone have an idea?
I use ArcGis 10.2 Advanced.

Comment: What's the meaning of 'move'? Does it means you need a precise shift of the point? or just centering the nearest grid? or other? I got an idea using python.